# How do I install mysql gem using bundler? (OS X Lion)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems

So, I currently have to do this to install the mysql gem:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" ; sudo gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -v 2.7 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

now, in bundler, I'd do something like

```
gem "mysql", "2.7"
```

which gives the error:

```
uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes
```

because the mysql gem isn't built right.

EDIT: oh, I'm also using RVM.
What I i'm going to try, is re-install the mysql gem normally (the long command), and try copying it into the rvm directory.

I'm on OS X Lion

Comment: what OS are you using? (I'm running RoR on ubuntu box, and followed partially ryan bigg's guide for installing - mysql working almost out of the box); why is mysql in your usr/local folder? and do you specifically need mysql? usually sqlite3 is fine, at least for development

Comment: OS X Lion =\ mysql is in the usr/local folder, cause the instructions told me to put it there =\ (should it be elsewhere?).  I do need mysql. =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.

I fixed the problem (kinda) by not using a gemset.
So, all my gems for this project are in the main ruby 1.8.7 environment inside ~/.rvm/.

=\

So.. that's one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

use

gem install mysql2 -v 0.2.6

instead of

gem "mysql", "2.7"